# How do you print utmp struct's data in utmp.h?

Tags: c, unix, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I want to learn to use the functions and data structures that come with utmp.h.
In the code below I wanted to iterate through the utmp structs and print their data fiels.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utmp.h>

int main()
{
        struct utmp *data;
        data = getutent();
        int i = 0 ;
        while(data != NULL)
        {
                ++i;
                printf("%s\n" , data->ut_id);
                data = getutent();
        }
        printf("%d" , i);
        return 0 ;
}
```

Even though `ut_id` is of type `char[4]`, when I run the code I get this warning:

*warning: ‘__builtin_puts’ argument 1 declared attribute ‘nonstring’ [-Wstringop-overflow=]*

How can I fix it?

Comment: That field probably isn't for a 0-terminated C string and shouldn't be used with functions that expect one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is the result of the gcc-specific attribute `__attribute_nonstring__`, which is used as an indicator that an array of characters does not necessarily end in a `NUL` character, and therefore may not be safe to use with the standard library string functions. The `utmp` struct in Linux is defined with that attribute on its character array fields.

To work around that warning, you can use the `printf()` modifier `%.*s` which specifies the fixed width output of a character array, like this:

```
printf("%.*s\n" , (int)(sizeof data->ut_id), data->ut_id);
```

(you could just use `4` for the second argument, but `sizeof` is more flexible).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you explained it perfectly. It's the first time I encounter __attribute_nonstring__ . 
So if anybody else had this problem, some fields of the utmp struct have __attribute_nonstring__.